# Ruby on Rails - Suppress an error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3 and AJAX and have a parent object which is being created through and AJAX request. This parent is sent with children and saves them all. However, if a child has an error, Rails will stop the request. Is there any way to tell Rails to ignore this? I understand the proper thing to do is find the problem within the Javascript sending the request and fix it. However, for the sake of learning, is there a way to tell Rails that some errors might be ignorable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save without validating use:

```
@parent.save(:validate => false)
```

Also, don't forget you can create conditional validation rules if needs be.  For example, add a virtual attribute (an instance variable that is not persisted to the DB) accessible via bare_bones?.  Then modify a validator like so:

```
validates_presence_of :nickname, :unless => "bare_bones?"
```

Then, in your controller you would do something like this:

```
@parent = Parent.new params[:parent]
@parent.bare_bones = true
@parent.save()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for exception handling.

```
begin
  #code that may contain errors
rescue
  #what to do if an error is encountered
end
```

Comment: Well, it's not exactly an error. It's a failed validation. What I'm looking for is it to fail, of course. But, to ignore the fail, and just not take action. Still continue on doing everything else. In this case, continue saving other possibly passable children, and the parent model.